# while scrolling Images gets rotate in imageview in recycleview

Tags: android-recyclerview, bitmap, android-asynctask, imageview, android-glide

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3Cvp.jpg)loading 200 images from url in array and showing in recyclerview but while scrolling the rendered images gets rotate , it get tilt in the imageview. I have used Glide, Asynctask to load image.

For trial purpose I have showth 0th index image to check but still the image gets titl
[enter image description here][2]

in Adapter
Used Async Task
new DownloadImage(holder.imageView).execute(APIClient.baseUrl + "/" + item.getRestImg());

also tried glide
Glide.with(mContext).load(APIClient.baseUrl + "/" + item.getRestImg()).fitCenter().thumbnail(Glide.with(mContext).load(R.drawable.animationbg)).into(holder.imageView);

used this too
holder.imageView.setRotation(0);

AsyncTask Class

```
private class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView imageView;

    public DownloadImage(ImageView imageView) {
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... URL) {

        String imageURL = URL[0];

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imageURL).openStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```